# Extending a C:\ Bitlocker Encrypted partition

Tags: windows-7

I'm using a Windows 7 PC got a C:\ (bitlocker encrypted) partition that I would like to extend to some unallocated space free on the drive. However, I can't extend the partition (extend is grayed out). Is there any way I can do this?

[image]

Comment: You have to decrypt it first.

Comment: I'm not sure David is right or wrong about unencrypting it, but I'm pretty sure you can only Extend a partition Windows Disk Manager if the empty space is directly adjacent to the end of the partition you want to extend.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 [easus can't expand a blitlockered drive](http://forum.easeus.com/viewtopic.php?t=31322). I would imagine that applies to other partitioning software as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe I missed it -- Where did the OP mention Easus?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 He didn't. But it is well known software for partition management.